# $.parseJSON(data) not working

Tags: jquery, json

I know there are a LOT of this question on here. I took a whole day to search the same question. Nothing could answer mine! So please, don't close this saying that I'm just duplicating. 
I have a PHP file that is called on the same page as another js file, this PHP file encodes an array and echoes it on the same page (that's when it's called from an ajax request) like that:

```
$data = array(  
    "status" => $status,  
    "message" => $message,
);  

echo json_encode($data);
```

The values of $status and $message are determined by some conditions above them (which are not really important here). This PHP file is called at the top of the index file, so that means that the JSON is echoed before the `<!doctype html>` tag. Now, in the js file, here is the part in which I try to handle this JSON:

```
$.post($formUrl, $formData, function(data) {
  $data = $.parseJSON(data);
  alert($data.status);
});
```

Don't worry about the variables, they are not the problem. The only problem here is the `$data = $.parseJSON(data);` part. 
When I run this code. Nothing happens on success, but in the PHP file, there is an insertion command to the database which performs correctly. Everything works fine, except this JSON, I CAN'T GET IT!
When I try this:

```
$.post($formUrl, $formData, function() {
  $str = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}';
  $data = $.parseJSON($str);
  alert($data.a);
});
```

It works as expected, it alerts 1. So what I think the problem is, it's that the `$.parseJSON()` can't parse HTML files with JSON in them because as I told you, the PHP file echoes the JSON right before the  `< !doctype html >` . 
I'm so desperate right now. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you post the response from the server?

Comment: any errors in the firebug console or the chrome dev tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a die right after the json_encode. You could wrap the whole thing up in an if statement which will check that the $_POST is not empty. So on the first load, you'd just get the html, but on ajax post you'd get just the json.

Also try using this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    data: $formData,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", // this tells jquery to expect json back, and parses it automatically
    success: function(data) { alert(data.status) }  
})
```

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes!!! Thank you very much buddy! This is the right answer! In the PHP file, I added "die()" right after "echo json_encode($data);" then in the js file I used: `$.post($formUrl, $formData, function(data) {
   alert(data.status);
  }, 'json');` and it alerted the right key. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are outputting JSON from your PHP script on a page that also echoes HTML. You need a PHP script that exclusively echoes JSON. Also, in your PHP file,you may want to send a JSON MIME-type:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: +1, but `header` is not necessary since `$.parseJSON` is being used.

Comment: I might use that when I'll have a script outputting the JSON on another page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it easily..

Send fourth parameter as `json` to `$.post()` for `dataType`.

```
$.post($formUrl, $formData, function(data) {

  // after specifying the dataType you 
  // don't need to parse is manually by $.parseJSON()
  // jQuery will parse it for you

  // $data = $.parseJSON(data); //  remove this line

  console.log(data);

}, 'json');
```

Syntax of **[`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)** is:

```
$.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

you've to specify the last parameter `dataType`.